# setting input content failing

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, innerhtml

I have an html text input that I am trying to change the content of via an if statement - other actions within the if statement are occurring which tells me the if statement is reaching this action however the content is not changing as directed - is there an error in my code?

HTML:

```
<input id="quest17" class="tb8" type="text" name="quest[17]" value="" size="40">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('quest17').innerHTML = "new content";
```

is the problem because I also have a class? if so any way around it... I am honestly at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.value` instead of .innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('quest17').value = "new content";
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element is an input, `innerHTML` is the wrong way, try setting the `value` attribute

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('quest17').value = "new content";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value instead of innerHtml:

```
document.getElementById('quest17').value = "new content";​
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/8JqkQ/